# Percentage in table group

Tags: postgresql, table

I use PostgresSQL. Given table `t1`, I would like to obtain `result`. How to? The numbers on table result are the numbers on column `value1` divided by their sum. I utilize PostgresSQL server. I thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
(1, 10),
(1, 20),
(2, 10),
(2, 20),
(2, 20),
(3, 30),
(3, 20)

INSERT INTO result (id_, perc) VALUES
(1, 0.333),
(1, 0.666),
(2, 0.2),
(2, 0.4),
(2, 0.4),
(3, 0.6),
(3, 0.4)
```

Comment: Care to explain how you arrive at the desired numbers, or should we guess?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: The numbers on table result are the numbers on column value1 divided by their sum. I utilize  postgresSQL server.

Comment: What have you tried? Join your table to one with a sum and then perform the calculation on the new joined table!

Comment: Please add details by editing your question, don't leave them as comments.

Comment: You can do it without a window function - you originally said 5.7 was your server  - I thought this meant MySQL 5.7 - take [a look](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=731e18cad6a00d3fb713b184e3f487ca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what window functions are for:

```
select id_,  value1::float / sum(value1::float) over (partition by id_) from t1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8ced9bf03d1187602686b6e378148643)

Comment: Would the syntax be the following in case of two indexes?

`select id_1, id_2,  value1::float / sum(value1::float) over (partition by id_1, id_2) from t1`